# How to create a list of webform submissions for a particular webform

Tags: views, webforms

How to create a list of webform submissions for a particular webform. I have multiple Webforms on my site. I want to display list of Webform submissions for a particular webform only.
Tried to Use View module  but it shows all Webform submissions

Answer (score 1):

To view the submissions for a particular form you can just click the `Results` tab on the webform node, and you will have a list of submissions for that form, or go to `node/1/webform-results` where `1` is the node id.

You can also go to `Administration > Content > Webforms` (`admin/content/webform`) and click the `Submissions` link for the form you want to see the submissions for.

This is for Drupal 7 and Webform 3, but I believe it's more or less the same for the other versions.

Comment: webform-results doesnot have edit and delete links. I want to display webform submissions for a particular form having fields of form in table format with edit and delete link

Comment: The listing with submissions should have a table column named `Operations` which contains View, Edit, and Delete links. If you don't see them you could always try to switch admin theme.

Answer (score 0):

**View the list of all the Submissions**

- Login on the site as an Admin.
- From the Admin Menu, click on the Content link(admin/content)
- Click on the Webforms tab.
- It would list you all the Webforms that are there on the site.

[image]

- Click on the Submissions link (**node/[nid]/webform-results**)

[image]
 - Under Operations, we have the option to **Edit**, **View** and **Delete** the result.

Hope this answer help.